# How can I synchronize the value of a mat-slider with an input field (reactive form)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I would like to synchronize the `min` and `max` values of a ranged mat-slider with corresponding input fields. When I set numbers in the input fields the slider gets correct updated but when I use the slider to change the value of the input fields the slider behaves strange.

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="sampleForm">
    <input 
    type="number" 
    [min]="0" 
    [max]="sampleForm.value.max" 
    [formControlName]="'min'"
  >

    <input 
    type="number" 
    [min]="sampleForm.value.min" 
    [max]="100" 
    [formControlName]="'max'"
  >

  <mat-slider min="0" max="100">
    <input [formControlName]="'min'" matSliderStartThumb [value]="sampleForm.value.min">
    <input [formControlName]="'max'" matSliderEndThumb [value]="sampleForm.value.max">
  </mat-slider>
</form>
```

TS:

```
export class SliderRangeExample implements OnInit {
  sampleForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sampleForm = this.fb.group({
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
    });

    this.sampleForm.controls.min.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      this.sampleForm.controls.min.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
    });

    this.sampleForm.controls.max.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      this.sampleForm.controls.max.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
    });
  }
}
```

I can solve this by adding two more formControls to the sampleForm like inputMin and inputMax (using them for the input fields) and set the values in the subscription but I thought there is a better solution only using min and max. Highly appreciate any ideas on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use two "inputs" with the same `formControl`, but...

You can use [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) to change and show the value of a FormControl

Imagine you have a formControl `control`, you can write

```
<input [formControl]="control">
<input [ngModel]="control.value" 
       (ngModelChange)="control.setValue($event)">
```

So, in your case, you can use some like

```
<form *ngIf="sampleForm" [formGroup]="sampleForm">
  <input type="number" [min]="0" [max]="sampleForm.value.max"
    [ngModel]="sampleForm.get('min')?.value"
    (ngModelChange)="sampleForm.get('min')?.setValue($event)"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
  />

  <input type="number" [min]="sampleForm.value.min" [max]="100"
    [ngModel]="sampleForm.get('max')?.value"
    (ngModelChange)="sampleForm.get('max')?.setValue($event)"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
  />

  <mat-slider min="0" max="100">
    <input formControlName="min" matSliderStartThumb/>
    <input formControlName="'max'" matSliderEndThumb/>
  </mat-slider>
</form>
```

See that you need use `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"` because you're using a `[ngModel]` inside a `FomGroup`

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6quats?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

1. NOTE: I choose the inputs type number to transform the
   `FormControlName`y `ngModel`, but you can also choose the inputs in
   sliders
2. NOTE2: see that when you use a formControl **NOT** use `[value]`
3. NOTE3: you can use `formControlName="min"` instead of
   `[formControlName]="'min'"`, it's unnecessary "binding" if it's a
   constant.